# how lightboxes for pics works? they use iframes? how they download pics?

Tags: javascript

how lightboxes for pics works? they use iframes? how they download pics?

Comment: try to make question more clear, not just throwing three sentences into the room.

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to a modal dialog. A translucent overlay is put over the entire screen. A DIV is placed over top of the overlay that displays the picture and controls. Images are usually supplied as a list. It's all JavaScript and CSS. JavaScript is used to flip the images.

Answer (score 0):

Usually just by creating an `<img>` element with JS and DOM.